# Unable to Connect to Neo4j using NeoClient for PHP

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I'm new to Neo4j. I'm using Neo4jPHP with WAMP to try to test my connection to my Neo4j Database with the following code:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client('localhost', 7474);
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

But when I run the code above, I get these errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command.php on line 116
>
> Everyman\Neo4j\Exception: Unable to retrieve server info [401]: Headers: Array ( [Date] => Tue, 08 Sep 2015 21:48:28 GMT [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [WWW-Authenticate] => None [Content-Length] => 144 [Server] => Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT) ) Body: Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message] => No authorization header supplied. [code] => Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed ) ) ) in C:\wamp\www\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command.php on line 116

As I said, I'm new to Neo4j, so I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Neo4j is running and I've been able to test it by connecting to `localhost:7474`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the 401 means that Neo4j is requiring authentication.  Looking at neo4jphp I'm not sure that it supports Neo4j's on-by-default authentication which was introduced in Neo4j 2.2.0.

You could check out [NeoClient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient).  From the README the code to connect with a username and password would be something like:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', 'http', 'myserver.dev', 7474, true, 'username', 'password')
    ->build();
```

If you really want to use neo4jphp you could disable authentication (of course not recommended unless you've otherwise secured the database).  There is also this issue on the repo which might be helpful:

https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues/165

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed your suggestion and tried NeoClient, I got a similar error about 401, however, I followed some suggestions from another post about NeoClient which said to turn off authentication and I'm now able to connect. Is it safe to turn off authentication??

Comment: Turning it off is fine for local testing/development.  If you're hosting the database somewhere where people can access it then you'll probably want to revisit that.

Comment: One thing that I forgot to mention: the default username/password is `neo4j`/`neo4j`.  You change that when you first log into the web console

Comment: NeoClient supports Neo4J2.x Authentication. I would suggest you check your credentials. Turning off authentication is NOT a solution nor something to advise.

Answer (score 0):

this may solve the problem. Replace HOSTNAME, PORT, USER and PASSWORD with your values.

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(HOSTNAME, PORT);
$client->getTransport()->setAuth(USER, PASSWORD);
```